# What is the incantation of the apparition spell?

Tags: harry-potter, apparition

Is there any canon reference of someone saying an incantation when apparating?

I don't remember one and even on the lessons in the sixth year, the teacher never mentions any.

Comment: There isn’t one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a spell. We see the complete instructions, and it doesn't have a spell:

> He waved his wand. Old-fashioned wooden hoops instantly appeared on the floor in from of every student.
>
> “The important things to remember when Apparating are the three D’s!” said Twycross. “Destination, Determination, Deliberation!
>
> “Step one: fix your mind firmly upon the desired destination,” said Twycross. “In this case, the interior of your hoop. Kindly concentrate upon that destination now.”
>
> “Step two,” said Twycross, “focus your determination to occupy the visualised space! Let your yearning to enter it flood from your mind to every particle of your body! “
>
> “Step three,” called Twycross, “only when I give the command... turn on the spot, feeling your way into nothingness, moving with deliberation. On my command, now... one —”
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 18</sub>

Comment: Quote taken from [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102848/33591) by @Vishvesh.